# Header already sent error i am using cURL php dompdf

Tags: php, curl, dompdf

i am building some reports my code works fine on localhost but gives error on server, how should i fix this...

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /localhost/prepare.php:1) in /localhost/prepare.php on line 2
Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent
```

here it is prepare.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['usercode']) && isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/report/formats/'.$_GET['id'].'.php?id='.$_SESSION['usercode']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $st = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
    $my_html = curl_exec($ch);
    if($st==200)
       $my_html="Oops! Something went wrong...$st";
    curl_close($ch);

    require_once("./domppdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($my_html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("report.pdf", array('Attachment'=>'0'));
}
?>
```

Comment: encoding is `Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch`

Comment: I believe you misunderstood. The file itself has an encoding. Please check my answer for a more thorough explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error appears, because you've output ANYTHING to the user client (the browser) before starting the session.

Judging from your code, I believe it to be a 'byte order mask' (also called BOM), which usually is used to determine, whether the first byte of a multibyte sign is the MSB or the LSB.

This code is invisible in any text editor which supports it and will appear as a diamond with question mark in those who don't.

If you don't know if you've got BOM enabled or not, feel free to open your source file with a hex editor and check if the first characters are `<?php` or something else.

A good text editor will allow you to choose the encoding. `UTF8 without BOM` is a good choice and `Notepad++` is a good editor in my opinion.

Comment: i checked my code using notepad++ and there is no such character... :(

Comment: @tomcat You checked the encoding, yes? It's in the menu bar under 'Encoding' (or whatever your localized name is, I'm from Germany, so for me it's 'Kodierung')

Comment: @tomcat And there's absolutely nothing in front of the <?php, right? Not even a space?

Comment: Thanks brother you just saved me a lot of time, i wish if it was possible to give you many up(s), i would have given you like thousand up(s) (y)...

Comment: @tomcat You're welcome, and one (and a accept) is more than enough. After all, we're all here to help (and get help) :)

Comment: still i faced this problem like 5 times ago but couldnt solve, and you did it :)

Comment: @tomcat Don't ask me how much time I spent when I ran into that problem the first time myself. This kinda experience tends to etch these things into your mind. :)